# Convert JSON response suitable for Google Maps Api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My Server send a response to the client , an array of json

```
["{"lat":27.4924,"lon":77.6737}", "{"lat":27.4924,"lon":77.6737}"]
```

First of all , I need to replace lon attribute with lng (cause Google Maps Api doesn't accept lon as attribute ) , and then I need to delete the external double quotes for each element of the array. I'm a little bit confusing and I don't know how to procede ,

> cause JSON.parse throw an error(Unexpected token with JSON.parse).

I don't want code , any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

This is my server asking to the Api

```
function request (array){
    let risposte = [];
    for (i=0; i<array.length;i++){
      var Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var url = "http://ip-api.com/json/" + array[i]+"?fields=lat,lon";
    Http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (Http.readyState ==4){
      if(Http.status == 200){
        console.log("qui" + i);
        console.log("Risposta" + Http.responseText);
        risposte.push(Http.responseText);
       }
       if (Http.status==400){
        console.log("servizio momoentanamente non disponibile ");
       }
  }
};
Http.open("GET",url,false);
Http.send();
  }
  console.log("finito");
  return risposte;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest not modifying the string as it is, but parsing it - the creating json from your parsed values.

Comment: It looks like you are receiving Arrays as Strings in the response from server. Ideal would be to make changes server side to send the response correctly or if it cannot be modified, then you may need to have your own utility to convert it to the Google Map input format

Comment: Third party Api response to my server without double quotes , so a valid Json , but my server response to my client with the same data but adding double quotes for each element of the array, so in this case it's not a valid json

Comment: Hi @FedericoFioravanti Can you share the code you are using to bypass the data from the third party API to you client. Maybe it would be a good approach to fix the response from them to do less processing on client side.

Comment: @FedericoFioravanti - Why is your server adding double quotes on top of JSON input which is already valid (as you have mentioned in your comment)?

Comment: Edited my code , then i perform res.json(array) to my client

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not modifying the string as it is, but parsing it - the creating json from you parsed values (commented above).  Or, for a dirty solution, you could just remove all the quotes, and do a string replace - it would be valid JSON:

```
var cleaned = yourJson.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Replace("lon", "lng");
```

But that just feels wrong to me!